# Live Chat EndChatState does not seem to handle errors vs successfully completed chat

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud

I am building a custom Live Agent Chat page in Visualforce. There are three states for the chat page, waiting, chatting, and end. These are the three documented by Salesforce with example code. The issue I am having is the with the end state. You seem to get to the end state if you had a successful chat or if an error occurred (no agents available, no flash installed...). I want to display a different message to the end user if the chat was completed v.s. if an error occurred. Is there any way to detect the difference between these two states?